# Google Maps Images Outdated

Tags: google-maps-api-3

When using the API the images in some situations are outdated compared to what is provided in the public Google Maps interface.

Is there anything we can do about this?

Regards
Jeremy

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't anything you can do about that, other than possibly to select different versions of the Maps API or to select the "visual refresh" in the API.

The Maps API and the Google Maps site don't use the same map tiles and imagery. Much is common between the two, and they tend to sync up over time, but it will always vary as new releases of each come out.